# How to bitbake copy a prebuilt static library into the sdk

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

**Scenario:**
I am working with yocto linux recipes. I am trying to make a recipe which simply copies a prebuilt `MyLibrary.a` and its headers available on the built linux image. So, I have a `libMyLibrary.a` which I want to copy to `/usr/lib`. And `MyLibrary`'s headers files `MyLibrary.h` and `MyLibrary.hpp` into `/usr/include`. Note that `MyLibrary` is already built and I just want to copy the binary and headers into desired locations of the built linux image.

So following is the recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Script to make a static library available in yocto linux image"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}"

SRC_URI = "file://libMyLibrary.a \
           file://MyLibrary..hpp \
           file://MyLibrary..h \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -d ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/libMyLibrary.a ${D}${libdir}/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/MyLibrary.h ${D}${includedir}/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/MyLibrary.hpp ${D}${includedir}/
}
```

Initially I started with getting some errors in the `do_install` step. I resolved them but now the `do_rootfs` step is complaining about my `bb` file that is `mylibrary_1.0.bb`. I am pretty sure that the parent recipe that calls my recipe has no errors since it builds a lot of other recipes and mine is just additional to it. Also, the errors started to appear after I wrote the `do_install` step.

**Question**
Can someone point out what is wrong with my recipe above?
Or is there a simple example recipe which copies a `.a` and its headers into the desired location i.e. `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` like I am doing above?

Answer (score 1):

Explaining what the errors are would be useful.  Note that because your recipe only ships a static library and headers it won't generate a mylibrary package, which is probably what the errors are about.

Comment: Gives me at least some idea of what might be going wrong. Thanks.